# Uploading only html files using gsutil?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

This seems like a really basic question but I can't seem to make it work.

I am using a static site generator for a website. I want to set all my html files to never be cached and all the rest to be cached. To do this, I'd like to upload all non-html files and set the cache headers. This is straight forward using:

`gsutil -m -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000" rsync -x ".*\.html$" -r dist/ gs://bucket/`

But how do I then upload only my html files? I've tried cp and rsync with wildcards, but I try something like:

`gsutil -h "Content-Type:text/html" -h "Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" rsync -r 'dist/**.html' gs://bucket/`

I get: `CommandException: Destination ('dist/**.html') must match exactly 1 URL`

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy the files into the bucket so have to use "cp" command.

Try the following code:

```
gsutil -h "Content-Type:text/html" -h "Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" cp dist/**.html  gs://YOUR_BUCKET
```

Comment: When I run this command: ```gsutil -h "Content-Type:text/html" -h "Cache-Control:private, max-age=0, no-transform" cp 'dist/**.html' gs://bucket```

I get this error: ```CommandException: No URLs matched: 'dist/**.html'```

This is despite there being several HTML files in the ```dist/``` directory.

Comment: Try to put 'dist/**.html' without quotes like this dist/**.html

Comment: Makes no difference. Surely there is a way to do this on the command line?

Comment: I run the previous code and I was able to upload the html files to the bucket. I think that you are running this command from the wrong directory. Can you just make sure that you are running the command from the folder in which the dist directory is located?